# remove selection using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a image viewer that has a draggable scrollbar. When the user drags the scrollbar, some of the text on the webpage becomes selected. I've tried

```
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

but that doesn't seem to work in IE7/8. Also tried the

```
document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

which seems to work just as "well" with IE7/8.

Are there any other ways of doing this? Don't know of any jQuery solutions, but if there are, let me know (:

**EDIT:** This is the context of the onmouse-event

```
$("#slideBar").mousedown(function(f) {
    mouseDown = true;
    some more code...
}

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    if (mouseDown) {
       window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
       more code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try returning false on the functions you use, especially for the "mousedown" event. Also returning false on document.onselectstart and document.ondragstart would help.

Comment: ‘return false’ on your element's ‘ondragstart’ is essential for IE, and the same with ‘onmousedown’ for others. This is a better approach than trying to ‘removeAllRanges’.

Answer (score 4):

You could add some CSS (with jquery) to deal with this:

```
element {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Anyway, for IE, you need to add a proprietary attribute (with jquery) on that element:

```
unselectable="on"
```

Comment: does the attribute have to be added to the element that contains the text, or can it be for the parent element that holds all text elements? Because I can't seem to get it to work in IE setting unselectable on the element that holds the whole image viewer.

Comment: According to the MSDN docs, it's not possible (can't post the link, google "msdn unselectable"). I had no idea about this. Give it a try using BYK's method, it should work in IE.